# To display UIButtons in GridView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton

I have some number of buttons(5 UIButtons) and want to place them in grid view in each row i want to place 3 buttons.

How can i place them, Any idea?

```
-(void)createSubMenusforView:(UIView *)selectedView
{
int y=75;

for(int i=0;i<=([arr count]-1)/3;i++)
{
    int si=(selectedView.frame.size.width/3-50)/2;

    int x=si+si/2;

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        UIButton *btn_item=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50,50)];
        btn_item.backgroundColor=[UIColor  grayColor];
        [selectedView addSubview:btn_item];

        [self doAnimateforView:btn_item forFrame:CGRectMake(btn_item.frame.origin.x, btn_item.frame.origin.y, btn_item.frame.size.width, btn_item.frame.size.height) forDelay:0.5];

        x=x+75;

    }

    y=y+60;

}
}
```

Comment: show your efforts in question, please

Comment: But Its not working i know i missed logic if found guide me thanks

Comment: you want to show only 5 buttons or more than 5 buttons? because if it is more than 5 buttons then create customTableCell with 3 buttons in it, give number of buttons array as datasource to TableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one global button count, `int totalButton=5;`

And used tableView to show Gridview, following code will help you to solve your problem, it is generalise code, you can add more than 5 button in Gridview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // add tableView on your View or thr xib
       tableView.delegate=self;
       tableView.dataSource=self;                
       [self.view addSubView:tableview]; 

}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

//@required

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    int numberOfRows=totalButton/3;
    if(totalButton%3)
        numberOfRows++;
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // You can create custom cell with xib and drag drop 3 buttons on it and handle the logic to show total buttons on tableview
   // Here I am adding buttons as subView to cell 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // No cell to reuse => create a new one
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease]; 

        // Initialize cell
        int numberOfRows=totalButton/3;
        if(totalButton%3)
           numberOfRows++;

        if(indexPath.row < numberOfRows) {
          int x=10;
          for(int i=0; i< 3;i++) {

               UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
               //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
               [button.titleLabel setText:@"Button"];
               button.tag=i+1;
               button.frame = CGRectMake(x, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0);
               [cell addSubview:button];
               x+=70; 
          }
        }
        else {

              int x=10;
          for(int i=0; i< totalButton%3;i++) {

               UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
               //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
               [button.titleLabel setText:@"Button"];
               button.tag=i+1;
               button.frame = CGRectMake(x, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0);
               [cell addSubview:button];
               x+=70; 
          }
        }
    }

    // Customize cell

    return cell;
}
```